# DataTemplate doesn't get shown?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, stackpanel

I have the following xaml code in resources:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:Substance}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="20" Background="Blue"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Count,  Converter={StaticResource stringToIntConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="20" Background="Yellow"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

`Substance` derives from `ContentControl`:

```
public partial class Substance : ContentControl
{
    string name; public int count; SymbolTable symTable = null;
    public Substance(string _name, int _count, SymbolTable _symTable)
    {
        symTable = _symTable; Name = _name; Count = _count; 
    }
}
```

`Name` and `Count` are DPs defined in another partial class definition.

When I added a substance in a `StackPanel` or `ListBox` nothing gets shown:

```
Substance s = new Substance("newSub", 100, symTable);
substancePanel.Children.Add(s);
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't i tell you not to make `Substance` inherit from a UI-related class?

If you disregard that `DataTemplates` will not be applied (depending on expected type), but even worse than that you break the model-view-separation.

Comment: Hrrrm I didn't even notice that inheritance

Comment: @Rachel: I expected it when i opened up the question :P

Comment: @H.B. You are correct, apologies. It works when I add to a ListBox but when I add it to a panel it doesn't get displayed, if I want to achieve both, should I inherit from ContentControl and provide a ControlTemplate (As a side note, a control cannot have both a DataTemplate and a Controltemplate right?

Comment: @mihajlv: No, stop it, **now**! Don't make it inherit for **anything**. *Substance* is **data** if you want to **data**-template it you cannot make it a control which itself dictates how it is displayed (which is bad design). Also you should never add items directly to a panel, and if you **stop the mad inheritance** you will get the exception you deserve, because **you cannot add non-ui-elements to a panel**.

Comment: @H.B. I see, it makes sense now, it was a dumb comment. Apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: @mihajlv: Don't worry about that, i am wasting my time volutarily after all.